# Ubuntu 18.04 - Catkin_make -> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11::X11

Tags: linux, x11, catkin

My problem is the following:
I am trying to run some ROS packages. I have already did it on a virtual machine so the packages are correct. I want now to do the same on my parition, I installed the libraries I needed but when I run `catkin_make` I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11::X11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
acin_reconstruction/CMakeFiles/reconstruction_node.dir/build.make:245: recipe for target '/home/vanessa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/acin_reconstruction/reconstruction_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/vanessa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/acin_reconstruction/reconstruction_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6388: recipe for target 'acin_reconstruction/CMakeFiles/reconstruction_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [acin_reconstruction/CMakeFiles/reconstruction_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed"
```

I didn't find any solution on internet but I read a post in which a guy was using the following commands and so I write here the outputs

`ld -lX11 --verbose`:

```
 GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.sec        : { *(.plt.sec) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


>==================================================
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so succeeded
-lX11 (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so)
libxcb.so.1 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 failed
found libxcb.so.1 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
libdl.so.2 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libdl.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 failed
found libdl.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 failed
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libXau.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 failed
found libXau.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
libXdmcp.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 failed
found libXdmcp.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libbsd.so.0 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libbsd.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 failed
found libbsd.so.0 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0
librt.so.1 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/librt.so.1 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 failed
found librt.so.1 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
libpthread.so.0 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
attempt to open /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //lib/i686-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 failed
found libpthread.so.0 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

`locate libX11`:

```
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/snap/sublime-text/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/snap/sublime-text/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/libX11
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/libX11-keys.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/libX11-keys.html.db
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/libX11-keys.pdf.db.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/libX11-keys.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/libX11/libX11.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/libX11/libX11.html.db
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/libX11/libX11.pdf.db.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/libX11/libX11.txt.gz
```

I am not an expert of ubuntu and for this reason I don't know what to do. I have alread tried sudo `apt-get install lib11-dev` or similar commands witouth results.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks for your time.